# Prove the identity of $\cosh(\ln x)= \frac{x^2 + 1}{2x}$

Tags: calculus

$\cosh(\ln x)= \frac{x^{2}+1}{2x}$

I know that $\cosh x = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$

I'm not sure if I am supposed to use this in order to prove the identity.

Couldn't I just take the derivative to prove that the identity is true?

Comment: Use the fact that $e^{\ln x}=x$.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$, that is, start putting dollar signs (\$) around your math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since ${ e }^{ \ln { x }  }=x$

> $$\frac { { e }^{ \ln { x }  }+{ e }^{ -\ln { x }  } }{ 2 } =\frac { x+{ x }^{ -1 } }{ 2 } =\frac { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }{ 2x } $$

Answer (score 1):

$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \Rightarrow \cosh(\log(x))=\frac{e^{\log(x)}+e^{-\log(x)}}{2}=\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}$ (why does this last equality follow?) -- can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you, I completely forgot that e^lnx = x. I understand the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Other formulae for the hyperbolic functions, that every one should know by heart, make this obvious:
\begin{align*}
\cosh x &=\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}+1}{2\mathrm e^x},&
\sinh x &=\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-1}{2\mathrm e^x},&
\tanh x &=\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-1}{\mathrm e^{2x}+1}.
\end{align*}